# Best practice for autoscaling virtual machines

Tags: cluster, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

when i create a clustered environment on Google Cloud Platform i create a vm image and from there i enable autoscaling based on this image.

Let's say i need to change anything on this vm, like a small config to nginx or php: i usually recreate the image with my new changes and give this new image to autoscaler.

I would like to know is there is any best practice that allows me to edit configs without recrrating the image, many times i just change a small patameter like buffers or increasre php childs..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are different options that you can consider to use for configuring your image and resources to achieve your goal. One of the option is using [Google Cloud Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/) that allows you to deploy, manage and update your applications and resources using templates and configuration files. There are two advanced examples of using deployment manager on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/tutorials).

However, since you mentioned that you just want to apply smaller changes on your template's image wiihtout building a new one, I'd suggest using [start-up script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) with your template. As EEAA said in his answer, this could introduce some latency in readiness of the new instances, however it depends on what changes you're applying to your template's image and how much latency would impact your application performance. For example, if the start-up script is installing a new package and its dependencies on new VMs which installation lets say takes 2 minutes, then you may want to rebuild a new image for your template with all those updates in place. But for changing patameters like buffers or increasing PHP childs the latency of changing these parameters using start-up script should be negligible.

Comment: Since autoscaler will always use the template to replace or create new VMs, the template needs to be updated.  As mentioned by Kamran, you can update the metadata of the template to run startup scripts when the VM is created and perform some tweaks .  There is also a nice [alpha feature](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups) that let you update progressively  the instances inside a managed to a group.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, instead of pre-configuring everything and baking it into the image, have the autoscaling node configure themselves on boot using some sort of configuration management.

I do this using Ansible in AWS - the images boot up, download an ansible playbook, and then apply it.

One negative of this approach is that it introduces some latency in availability of newly-created nodes. If this is a problem, you can take a hybrid approach and have most of your changes baked into the image, and use boot-time configuration management for small incremental changes.

Comment: I was thinking about including some extra config file from outside like cloud storage and then just reload nginx for changes to take effect. Could this work?

Comment: Sure. Generally-speaking, you should try and not reinvent the wheel with regards to configuration management. Being able to programmatically re-build your images from a "bare" OS is *very* nice, and keeps you honest with regards to how you're managing things. So, even if you're just applying a simple nginx config, it's worth it IMHO to do it using ansible, which will give you a clear path to growing your configuration management over time, using a well-understood, well-supported product instead of something homebrew.

Comment: Thx for the feedback, i was wondering of anyone else in this position and what is the strategy choosen to add some small config without recreating the image..